# How can I build a dynamic absolute path in PHP?

Tags: php, directory, include, filepath

I've a web site made of some folders, one for each section (info, news, blog etc...).
In each of these folders there is an `index.php` file that should load a layout (common to all). These are stored in a different folder in the root where there is also the main `index.php` file (the homepage). So i have something like this:

```
root
-index.php (home)
-/layout
--layout files
-/info
--index.php`
```

The index file in the `/info` folder should include the page layout from `/layout`.
The problem is that the layout files should include other files from other folders.
In layout files I put this:

```
include 'contents/page-element.php';
```

But if I try to reach the same `page-element.php` file from the `index.php` file in the `/info` folder, I should do:

```
include '../contents/page-element.php';
```

to go to the root and then reach the `/layout` folder.

I don't want to create a copy of the layout for the folders so I've tried `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, but it does not work in some cases on the localhost and even on the web server.

Can someone help me or let me know how I can build a dynamic absolute path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the built-in constant `__DIR__` you can get your absolute `path`

by print it or save

```
echo __DIR__;
```

it will print something like this for you

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\test
```

and there is also another constant that will get the absolute `path` for your file that executes the command `__FILE__`

```
echo __FILE__;
```

will give you a result like this

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\index.php
```

Comment: Thanks, tomorrow I'll try that. Btw, I knew the `__DIR__` solution and it does not solve the problem, because if I write `include __DIR__.'test.php';` and move the file that contains the include request to a deeper folder, it won't include the requested file.